# How can I listen to external devices controls (earbuds for example) in React Native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

I am building a Workout Timer application and I would like to be able to detect when a user clicks on his airpods/galaxy buds and call a function in code.

I tried to install and use various libraries but none of them helped me solve my problem. The only one that looked promising is react-native-track-player but when I use it (maybe because it is not compatible with Expo) it gives an error saying "Cannot read property 'RATING_HEART' of null, js engine: hermes" and I can't find the solution to it.